# Optimization of C code for hypergeometric distribution

Tags: c, optimization

I have to optimize the given C code :-

```
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define GAP(start, end) ((end.tv_usec-start.tv_usec)+(end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec)*1000000)
void main(){
    struct timeval start_time, end_time;
    gettimeofday(&start_time, NULL);
    /* START OF BLOCK */
    long int n, N, e, E, e_choose_i, E_e_choose_N_i, E_choose_N;
    float p_value = 0;
    long int i, var1, var2, var3, var4; // Temporary variables
    fscanf(stdin, "%ld%ld%ld%ld", &n, &N, &e, &E);
    for(i = n; i <= N; i++){
        for(var1 = 1, var4 = 2; var4 <= e; var4++)
            var1 = var1 * var4; // Computes e!
        for(var2 = 1, var4 = 2; var4 <= i; var4++)
            var2 = var2 * var4; // Computes i!
        for(var3 = 1, var4 = 2; var4 <= e-i; var4++)
            var3 = var3 * var4; // Computes (e-i)!
        e_choose_i = var1/(var2*var3); // Computes (e choose i)
        for(var1 = 1, var4 = 2; var4 <= (E-e); var4++)
            var1 = var1 * var4; // Computes (E-e)!
        for(var2 = 1, var4 = 2; var4 <= (N-i); var4++)
            var2 = var2 * var4; // Computes (N-i)!
        for(var3 = 1, var4 = 2; var4 <= ((E-e)-(N-i)); var4++)
            var3 = var3 * var4; // Computes ((E-e)-(N-i))!
        E_e_choose_N_i = var1/(var2*var3); // Computes ((E-e) choose (N-i))
        p_value += e_choose_i*E_e_choose_N_i;
    }
    for(var1 = 1, var4 = 2; var4 <= E; var4++)
        var1 = var1 * var4; // Computes E!
    for(var2 = 1, var4 = 2; var4 <= N; var4++)
        var2 = var2 * var4; // Computes N!
    for(var3 = 1, var4 = 2; var4 <= E-N; var4++)
        var3 = var3 * var4; // Computes (E-N)!
    E_choose_N = var1/(var2*var3); // Computes (E choose N)
    p_value /= E_choose_N;
    /* END OF BLOCK */
    gettimeofday(&end_time, NULL);
    printf("p-value = %f (%d microseconds)", p_value, (int) GAP(start_time, end_time));
}
```

I have used the dynamic programming approach to find the binomial coefficient and have modified the code as :-

```
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define GAP(start, end) ((end.tv_usec-start.tv_usec)+(end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec)*1000000)
void main(){
    struct timeval start_time, end_time;
    gettimeofday(&start_time, NULL);
    /* START OF BLOCK */
    long int n, N, e, E, e_choose_i, E_e_choose_N_i, E_choose_N;
    float p_value = 0;
    long int i; //var1, var2, var3, var4; // Temporary variables
    int p,q,r;
    fscanf(stdin, "%ld%ld%ld%ld", &n, &N, &e, &E);
    for(i = n; i <= N; i++){
        long int C[e+1][i+1];
        for(p=0;p<=e;p++)
        {
            r=(p<i)?p:i;
            for(q=0;q<=r;q++)
            {
                if(q==0 || q==p)
                    C[p][q]=1;
                else
                    C[p][q]=C[p-1][q-1]+C[p-1][q];
            }
        } 
        e_choose_i=C[e][i];
        long int C1[E-e+1][N-i+1];
        for(p=0;p<=E-e;p++)
        {
            r= (p<N-i)?p:N-i ;
            for(q=0;q<=r;q++)
            {
                if(q==0 || q==p)
                    C1[p][q]=1;
                else
                    C1[p][q]=C1[p-1][q-1]+C1[p-1][q];
            }
        } 
        E_e_choose_N_i = C1[E-e][N-i]; // Computes ((E-e) choose (N-i))
        p_value += e_choose_i*E_e_choose_N_i;
       }
     long int C2[E+1][N+1];
        for(p=0;p<=E;p++)
        {
            r= (p<N)?p:N ;
            for(q=0;q<=r;q++)
            {
                if(q==0 || q==p)
                    C2[p][q]=1;
                else
                    C2[p][q]=C2[p-1][q-1]+C2[p-1][q];
            }
        }   
    E_choose_N = C2[E][N]; // Computes (E choose N)
    p_value /= E_choose_N;
    /* END OF BLOCK */
    gettimeofday(&end_time, NULL);
    printf("p-value = %f (%d microseconds)", p_value, (int) GAP(start_time, end_time));
}
```

It is taking less time for small values say, n=2,N=3,e=3 and E=7 But it is taking more time for large values like n=3,N=8,e=10 and E=15. How to optimize it for large values. Please help.

Comment: You are including the fscanf in your timed sequence. This will take most of the time! It is always a good idea to time many calls of a function rather than one.

Comment: Thank you @dmuir. Can you please tell me, is there any other way to reduce the running time like writing optimize code for binomial coefficient or factorial without any loop or something ? Writing recursive code for factorial is taking more time than its iterative version. Can you please help  to optimize the given code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by [dmuir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2564696/dmuir)

> You are including the fscanf in your timed sequence. This will take most of the time! It is always a good idea to time many calls of a function rather than one.

Besides that, you can try a different method to evaluate the binomial coefficients:

```
double binomial(long n, long k)
{
    double result = 1.0;
    if ( k > n/2 )
        k = n - k;
    ++n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= k; ++i)
        result *= (double)(n - i) / i;
    return result;
}
```

So that the calculation (if I get it correctly) reduces to

```
for(int i = n; i <= N; i++)
{       
    p_value += binomial(e, i) * binomial(E - e, N - i);
}
p_value /= binomial(E, N);
```

Testable [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ce3AWAo1s5led53g).

Comment: Thank you @Bob__ for the answer. I am using gcc compiler. In terminal, your code is giving running time as  6379105 microseconds and the original code(without any modification in code) is giving running time as 4675572 microseconds and everytime when I compile it, it shows different running time. Can you please tell me why it is showing more running time and different running time ?

Comment: I mean, when I compile multiple times, each time it shows different running time. Can you please tell the reason behind it ?

Comment: @ankit Well profiling isn't a simple task. Every time you execute your program there may be different processes running at the same time, the data may be or not in the cache at different runs in the same execution and so on. [Here](http://quick-bench.com/RRD94c5_0_kcl7hmr8UJ0thc2gE) I tryed to compare the different implementations using a well known framework. You'll notice that, without memoization, my proposal is a pessimization too, compared to the original one.

Comment: @ankit Are you still including the fscanf in the timings? On my (ordinary) pc, computing the function for the values you gave takes a few microseconds, not a few seconds!

Comment: No, I replaced fscanf with 4 scanf statements at that time @dmuir. The problem is sometimes, it gives less running time and sometimes more running time as compared to original one after running the code as Bob__ suggested. May be the reason that other processes might be running as Bob said. Anyway, Thank you so much Bob__ and dmuir for the help :)

Comment: @ankit if the scanf's are inside your timing block, that's still the ptoblem. Since tou are measuring actual elapsed time (via gettimeofday) you are including the time it takes you to type in the numbers in your measure of how long it takes to do the the sums.

Comment: yeah, I got your point but is there any solution for it ? @dmuir

Comment: @ankit Move the first call of gettimeofday to just after the last scanf.

Comment: awesome.. Thank you so much @dmuir.  Time reduced a lot now.